# IBOutlets on second view controller help on swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, viewcontroller, iboutlet

On my first view controller I had no problem creating IBOutlets and Actions, but when I made another view controller, I couldn't make an IBOutlet. There was no blue line when I control dragged it and I couldn't make an IBOutlet and then connect it up either. The first view controller still works. Is it possible to make IBOutlets on two different view controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view controller must have a custom class file assigned to it in the identity inspector in InterfaceBuilder:

[image]

Then select the assistant editor and you should be able to ctrl-drag IBOutlets to the associated swift file.

Comment: I changed the name to the class but it is still not working. I think the problem is that the module for the second view controller says none. How would I make it so it says Current - Name Of The Project in the greyed out letters?

Comment: Did you select the correct file in the assistant editor?

Comment: Nevermind I messed something up before but i fixed it now, Thank You very much!

Comment: Ok, if that was the correct answer please mark it as accepted by clicking on the hollow checkmark. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have set the custom class for second view controller in your storyboard.

[image: Custom class for second view controller]

Comment: I think you didn't select the view controller. You have selected some view inside the second view controller and trying to set the custom class for that. Make sure you have selected the view controller and set the custom class. (Double tap the storyboard to zoom out and try to select the controller)

Answer (score 0):

it happens to me sometimes as well... and the reason it to use the new controller you need to create a new view controller file for it where you can use the iboutlets generally..
so you will be having one view controller file for each view controller. and you can follow the steps to do that.[image]

1. first of all delete the new view controller file if you have made any. and the new controller as well...
2. go to file new file choose cocoa class and then next and then write the name of the class you want e.g. **newcontroller** and make sure you choose uiviewcontroller in the next option and then click next and create.
3. create a new vie controller in the main.storyboard and then click on the new view controller and on the right hand side rename the class to **newcontroller**.
   once you Finnish all these three steps you will be able to use iboutlets for sure..

good luck..