# How to subclass different View Controllers in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, xcode6

How do I subclass different view controllers? This is what I've been trying to use:

```
class secondViewController: UIViewController {
```

This returns the error "Use of undeclared type UIViewController." What am I doing wrong?

I have started this class in a new .swift file, is that somehow contributing to the problem?

I would greatly appreciate a brief summary of what to do and a link to a GitHub repository that demonstrates how to do this.

Comment: Do you already have classes for your view controllers or that's what you have problems with? From your question I understand you have problems to connect your view with the created view controllers, I could be wrong though

Comment: I am trying to create classes for my view controllers. Do I need to use different files? I am going to add a link with how I am currently trying to declare the class for the second view controller.

Comment: No idea what you are asking. Are you talking about how to create a new class? Or how to connect something in a storyboard? Or a combination of both? There is no difference creating a class which is a subclass of UIViewController to creating a class which is a subclass of anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `import UIKit` at the top of the file if you are sub classing (or using) UIKit classes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I had was that I did not know how to connect my view controller to the class using the navigation panel, and I was importing foundation instead of importing UIKit. See this for more details:

[IBOutlets on second view controller help on swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27607737/iboutlets-on-second-view-controller-help-on-swift)